# Perl - regular expression to filter out last word

Tags: regex, perl

I have been working with a perl script and I've been trying to work with regular expressions to filter out the last word of each line from a system output.
I used the following command to list all services, the command is: "service --status-all" the command will output a list with all available services eg:

```
rdisc is stopped  
rpcbind (pid 1339) running...
```

I throw output into an array and chomping at every new line:

```
chomp(my @service_data_1 = qx/$command_3/);
```

I want to only print out the services that a user requests and inform the user if the service is currently running or is stopped.

I would like to know how to filter out the last word of each line using regex, I can't find any solutions to my problem anywhere and not here on stackoverflow.
Any help or input to this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: What, you mean like 'service <servicename> status' does?

Answer (score 1):

```
print ("\n$1") if(/(\s+\S+$)/);
```

This regex will print the last word of each line. `\s+` matches space, `\S+` matches anything except space. Together `\s+\S+$` matches space followed by any word including special chars at the end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex to match the last words.. and replace them with `''` (empty string)

```
\w+$     // but this wont match words ending with other than [a-zA-Z0-9_]
```